# Iterative interpolation

Tags: arcpy, interpolation

I have an excel file with about data from 600 locations, each location having data for 1200 months(12 months* 100 years). I need to interpolate all point locations into rasters for each month of each year separately. I understand I need a script to automate the process because it would be a huge number of rasters. Can anyone recommend me a similar script? 
I am absolutely new to GIS.

Comment: What interpolation method are you using?

Answer (score 2):

So you should have one point feature class per year, or one hundred feature class with 12 fields (it is not recommended to have more than 200 fields).

The best way if you work in ArcGIS is to use a python script.Here is an exmple for the second case:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy.sa import *
year=0
fcs = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()#list all your feature classes
for fc in fcs:
    month=0
    year+=1
    fields = [x.name for x in arcpy.ListFields(fc)] #list all your fields
    for field in fields[2:]: #loop on the fields while ignoring the first two fields (ID and shape)
        month+=1
        outIDW = Idw(fc, field) #add your parameter and chose your interpolation method, cellSize, power, searchRadius)
        outIDW.save("raster{0}_{1}.tif".format(year,month))
```

Comment: +1 for a simple scripting solution. You could incorporate `enumerate()` in your loop instead of manually incrementing.